# Filter current user products using queryset in DRF returns []

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to filter list of products linked with a user. I want to display only current users product instead of listing all.

I tried this

```
class ProductCreateList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return Product.objects.filter(user=user.id)
```

serializers.py

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['id', 'user', 'name', 'imgUrl', 'selling_price', 'actual_price', 'quantity', 'get_profit']
```

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('accounts.Account', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    imgUrl = models.TextField(default='')
    selling_price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    actual_price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

I got `[]` object when I tried to execute the endpoint. What's my mistake here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few mistakes, mainly in your view. I have done the following:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class Product(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    imgUrl = models.TextField(default='')
    selling_price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    actual_price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'product'
```

serializers.py: Remove 'get_profit' field or implement a [serializermethodfield](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from core.models import Product

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['id', 'user', 'name', 'imgUrl', 'selling_price', 'actual_price', 'quantity']
```

views.py: To filter by user, guarantee that the user is Authenticated and has auth permission by using **authentication_classes** and **permission_classes**. Use the **filter_queryset** hook, to filter your queryset by user.

```
from rest_framework.authentication import SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework import generics
from core.api.serializers import ProductSerializer
from core.models import Product

class ProductCreateList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication]  
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    queryset = Product.objects.all()

    def filter_queryset(self, queryset):
        queryset = queryset.filter(user=self.request.user)
        return super().filter_queryset(queryset)
```